# Migrating Facebook comments

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to migrate my old Facebook comments box to the new one. 
I added to my code 'migrated="1"', nothing else changed.

```
<fb:comments xid="myxid" url="/url/to/article" width="618" migrated="1"></fb:comments>
```

But old comments box is still there! Nothing happened, comments look the same. 
What do I do wrong?
Is there anything else I should do?

According to this article http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/472/, there should be nothing more required to migrate.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change the `url` parameter to `href`.